# How do I compile and run .java file with .class file in resource dynamically?

Tags: java, javacompiler

I'm trying to make my Main class print out in its console (eclipse) the output from Example1 class (in resources/ as .java file) that depends on Example2 class. I had this idea for grading purposes - to implement it in javafx application that runs a testing class (Example1) on a compiled class file found using FileChooser. I found out about using JavaCompiler, but I could not figure out how to use it to compile a .java file with a dependency on a .class file and execute it...

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import javax.tools.DiagnosticCollector;
import javax.tools.JavaCompiler;
import javax.tools.JavaFileObject;
import javax.tools.StandardJavaFileManager;
import javax.tools.ToolProvider;

public class Main {
    private static final String EXAMPLE1 = "resources/Example1.java";
    private static final String EXAMPLE2 = "resources/Example2.class";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JavaCompiler jc = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
        DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject> d = new DiagnosticCollector<>();
        StandardJavaFileManager fm = jc.getStandardFileManager(d, null, null);

        List<String> tag = new ArrayList<>();
        tag.add("-classpath");
        tag.add(System.getProperty("java.class.path") + File.pathSeparator + EXAMPLE2);

        File file = new File(EXAMPLE1);
        Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> cu = fm.getJavaFileObjectsFromFiles(Arrays.asList(file));
        JavaCompiler.CompilationTask task = jc.getTask(null, fm, null, tag, null, cu);

        /*
         * ?
         */
    }
}
```

Example1 as .java file in `resources/Example1.java`.

```
public class Example1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Example2 ex2 = new Example2(1, 2);
        System.out.println("x : " + ex2.x + ", y : " + ex2.y);
        System.out.println("sum : " + ex2.sum());
        System.out.println("mult : " + ex2.mult());
    }
}
```

Example2 as .class file in `resources/Example2.class`

```
public class Example2 {
    int x;
    int y;

    Example2(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int sum() {
        return x + y;
    }

    public int mult() {
        return x * y;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classpath must name the folder containing `Example2.class`, not the file name itself, so change the second `tag.add(...)` to `tag.add("resources")`.

You need to invoke `task.call()` to actually execute the compiler. The compiler will then place the `Example1.class` file next to the `Example1.java` file.

To run the class, you need to setup a `ClassLoader` with the `resources` folder in the classpath, then use reflection to get the `Example1` class and its `main` method.

`StandardJavaFileManager` and `URLClassLoader` are both *resources*, so you should use try-with-resources to correct close them when you're done with them.

Here is working code:

```
JavaCompiler jc = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject> d = new DiagnosticCollector<>();
try (StandardJavaFileManager fm = jc.getStandardFileManager(d, null, null)) {

    List<String> tag = new ArrayList<>();
    tag.add("-classpath");
    tag.add("resources");

    File file = new File(EXAMPLE1);
    Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> cu = fm.getJavaFileObjectsFromFiles(Arrays.asList(file));
    JavaCompiler.CompilationTask task = jc.getTask(null, fm, null, tag, null, cu);
    if (! task.call())
        throw new IllegalStateException("compilation failed");
}

try (URLClassLoader classLoader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[] { new File("resources").toURI().toURL() })) {
    Class<?> example1Class = Class.forName("Example1", true, classLoader);
    Method mainMethod = example1Class.getMethod("main", String[].class);
    if (! Modifier.isStatic(mainMethod.getModifiers()))
        throw new IllegalStateException("main method is not static");
    mainMethod.invoke(null, (Object) new String[0]);
}
```

If there is an error in `Example1.java`, you will get STDERR output like this:

```
resources\Example1.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
        xExample2 ex2 = new Example2(1, 2);
        ^
  symbol:   class xExample2
  location: class Example1
1 error
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: compilation failed
    at Test.main(Test.java:32)
```

If the class compiles, and has the correct name and method, the STDOUT output will be:

```
x : 1, y : 2
sum : 3
mult : 2
```